# Calculus question relating to the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is a twice-differentiable function with $f(0) = 0$, $f\left(\frac12\right) = \frac12$ and $f'(0) = 0$. Prove that $|f''(x)| \ge 4$ for some $x \in \left[0,\frac12\right]$.

I've been stuck on this question for a while now without any idea on how to get started.  Is it possible for someone to help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use Taylor's theorem to get $$f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=f(0)+\frac{1}{2}\cdot f'(0)+\frac{1}{8}\cdot f''(c)$$ for some $c\in(0,1/2)$ and your answer follows.

Note that the result can not be obtained by mean value theorem directly, but rather one should observe that proofs of mean value theorem and Taylor's theorem depend on Rolle's theorem.

Comment: That does it.  +1.   Interestingly, we find that $f''(c)=4$ for some $c$, and thus $|f''(c)|\ge 4$ for some $c$.  The result is sometimes called the extended mean value theorem.

Comment: @Dr.MV: thanks for the edits (and upvote too). I am bit lazy when typing on a phone.

Comment: Yes, these "Not-So-Smart" phones can be a challenge when posting herein.

Comment: @Dr.MV Haha, I've recently started trying to do this stuff on my phone, and it is most definitely of some difficulty.

Comment: @simpleart It is certainly more challenging to post a solution using a phone.

Answer (score 4):

[Paramanand's answer is definitely the way to go. I just want to share another elementary approach in the $f''$-is-continuous case.]

If $f$ is twice *continuously* differentiable then by the (second) *Fundamental theorem of Calculus* we can write
$$
f(x)=0+\int_0^xf'(y)\, dy=\int_0^x\left(0+\int_0^yf''(z)\, dz\right)dy.
$$
Plugging in $x=1/2$ and assuming that $|f''(z)|<4$ for $z\in[0,1/2]$ we arrive at the contradiction
$$
\frac{1}{2}=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^yf''(z)\, dz\, dy<\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^y4\, dz\, dy=\int_0^{1/2}4y\, dy=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Nice approach with some extra assumption. +1 I have taken the liberty to fix a minor typo.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I just learned that MathJax allows to use '\,' in math-mode, despite the fact that in text mode it doesn't allow '\ '. Thank you! :)